# angular ngx-infinite-scroll infinite scroll on mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use ngx-infinite scroll on mat-tab content
Html:

```
         <mat-tab-group *ngIf="tabs" (selectedIndexChange)="onTabSelected($event)" [tabIndex]="tabIndex">
                <mat-tab *ngFor="let t of tabs"
                [label]="t.name">
                    <div
                        infiniteScroll
                        fxLayout="column"
                        fxFlex="100"
                        (scrolled)="onScroll()">
                        <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>
                        <div  *ngIf="data"
                            fxLayout="row wrap"
                            fxLayoutGap="7px"
                            class="element-list">
                            <app-image-preview  class="selector-element"
                            *ngFor="let item of data"
                            [fxFlex]="widthProc"
                            [container]="item[container]"
                            [fileId]="item[image]"
                            [variant]="variant"
                            [caption]="item[caption]"
                            (onSelected)="onImageSelected($event,item)"
                            ></app-image-preview>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
```

The scroll is created on mat-tab-body-content it looks like. so the `infinitescroll` can not trigger

Any Idea what would be the correct way to get `infinitescroll` to work inside mat-tab ?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes will post the answer. Need to look back to that code